# Is it possible to register a class event handler in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible register a class event handler in WinRT?

In WPF this was possible via `EventManager.RegisterClassHandler`. Is there anything equivalent in WinRT?

Comment: It is not an available API since there are no routed events in Jupiter. What is the scenario where you need it? Most global events can be handled through Window.Current.CoreWindow.

Comment: Good to know. I was able to solve this problem by creating an attached boolean property that registered instance event handlers and having my default style set the attached property to true. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an available API since there are no routed events in Jupiter. What is the scenario where you need it? Most global events can be handled through Window.Current.CoreWindow.